# How to print html table next missing columns in new page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am unable to print next half columns in new Pages. Can any guide me how to do in CSS or HTML?

My client paper size is 8.5"x11" (Letter)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use media print

```
@media print {
  #your-table {
   overflow: visible;
  }
}
```

You can also change the look of the table on @media print. See this [example](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/wXgJww)
Just change these lines:

```
@media only screen 
    and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) 
    and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
```

fot this:

```
@media print {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `page-break-after`  property.
The properties: page-break-before, page-break-after and page-break-inside help to define how a document should behave when printed.

for more details https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp